# Youtube API - Some videos stuck on unstarted (-1) state

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I've been using Youtube Javascript API to play videos in a chromeless player, and recently some of the videos I am usually playing are not loaded in the player, and the player state stays on "unstarted" (-1). This is only for some of the videos (maybe a third of them, all the videos being music videos) and those videos were working ok before (the problem started 2-3 months ago). I don't think I've modified anything critical in my code, and the videos are still available on Youtube, so I don't know what happened.

This is how I create the player:

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", allowFullScreen: true};
var atts = { id: "myytplayer", class: "vid-embed" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3","ytapiplayer", "100%", "92%", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

I load the videos by using loadVideoById or loadVideoByUrl:

```
document.getElementById("myytplayer").loadVideoById("1dTCp3F8vGE");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myytplayer").loadVideoByUrl("http://www.youtube.com/v/1dTCp3F8vGE?version=3");
```

The video with ID otvhRsE5iqs is one of those that don't work, whereas the ID ZdKOo6yLf2Y is working for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think it's because I was still using Youtube Javascript API that was deprecated on January 27th (https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference). I changed the design to use an iframe and it seems to be working.

Comment: it happened to me with iframe API